# I'm writing a C program on visual studio. But my program doesn't run nor it returns any errors. Can someone take a look at it?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I hopelessly tried to copy paste this into another file but it still doesn't return anything.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "conio.h"
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)

typedef struct item
{
    char *pName;
    int Quantity, Price, Total;
} ITEM;

ITEM *Exam(char *pInput);

int main()
{
    ITEM *pItem;
    char input[81];
    printf("Type items: ");
    gets_s(input);
    char *pInput = input;
    pItem = Exam(pInput);
    printf("Name: %s\nQuantity: %d\nPrice: %d\nTotal: %d\n", pItem->pName, pItem->Quantity, pItem->Price, pItem->Total);
    free(pItem);
    return 0;
}

ITEM *Exam(char *pInput)
{
    ITEM *pItem = (ITEM *)malloc(sizeof(ITEM));
    char *pNam, *pQuantity, *pPrice;
    int total, l, q, p;
    int qu, pr;

    for (l = 0; *(pInput + l) != ','; l++);
    pNam = (char *)malloc(l + 1);
    *(pInput + l) = '\0';
    strcpy(pNam, pInput);
    pItem->pName = pNam;
    *(pInput + l) = ',';

    for (q = 0; *(pInput + l + 2 + q) != ','; q++);
    pQuantity = (char *)malloc(q + 1);
    *(pInput + l + q + 2) = 0;
    strcpy(pQuantity, pInput + l + 2);
    qu = atoi(pQuantity);
    pItem->Quantity = qu;

    for (p = 0; *(pInput + l + q + 4) != ';' || *(pInput + l + q + 4) != 0; p++);
    pPrice = (char *)malloc(p + 1);
    *(pInput + l + q + 4) = 0;
    strcpy(pPrice, pInput + l + q + 4);
    pr = atoi(pPrice);
    pItem->Price = pr;
    pItem->Total = pr * qu;
    return pItem;
}
```

input is 'shirt, 100, 5'. I want the output to be a structure of name, quantity, price and total. It let me type the input but when i press enter it doesn't return anything. The program just hangs...

Comment: First of all, why don't you use the *standard* [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function? Secondly, I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially how to run inside the debugger and how to catch crashes (which might be what you have).

Comment: Where does it hang?  (Attach a debugger.)

Comment: @Davis Herring after i type the input and hit enter. it doesn't do anything. It just stays there

Comment: @catify: And **what line** is running then?

Comment: What *is* the (exact!) input given?

Comment: @Davis Herring oh...51

Comment: I got why i'm wrong ! Thank you so much Davis Herring and programmer dude !

Comment: You should edit the question rather than clarify in comments.  The question says that it does not run, when it clearly does if it prompts for input.  VS has about the best debugger available - consider using it; it will be far faster that posting questions on SO.

Comment: @catify to use all these offsets complicate a lot your program, it is more simple to have a pointer going through the string, just my 2 cents

Comment: @bruno I have to use 'struct'. It's an assignment

Comment: @catify sorry if I wasn't clear, I speak about the offsets saved in the variables l q and p, in the block for you (must) have `pInput + l + q + 3 + p` while it can be a simple pointer or an alone index. Your code is wrong because of that (artificial) complexity

Comment: @bruno please show me how you could simplify this. Could you please post your code as another answer or may be, update your last answer? sorry if that's too much to ask. I just don't understand how a simple pointer would work but i really want to know.

Comment: You are misusing `gets_s()`. The correct prototype is `char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);` (see [C11 K.3.5.4.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.4.1)). **Turn on all your compiler warnings** and mind them.

Comment: @catify I edited my answer to add a proposal for Exam

Comment: @pmg *You are misusing `gets_s()`.*  True here, but in general, using the C standard to document Microsoft's versions of Annex K functions is likely to not match Microsoft's horrendous implementation.  [Per the ISO C committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm): "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last *for* in Exam is :

```
for (p = 0; *(pInput + l + q + 4) != ';' || *(pInput + l + q + 4) != 0; p++);
```

that *for* never end because its condition is always true

- if `*(pInput + l + q + 4)` values ';' the test is `false || true` then true
- if `*(pInput + l + q + 4)` values 0 the test is `true || false` then true
- for all the other characters the test is `true || true` so again true
- `+ 4` must be `+ 3` else goes 1 character too far
- and `p++` has no effect at all on the test

The test can be changed to `!(*(pInput + l + q + 3 + p) == ';' || *(pInput + l + q + 3  + p) == 0)` to stop when ';' or the null character is reached

Of course after `*(pInput + l + q + 4) = 0;` must be `*(pInput + l + q + 3 + p) = 0;`

Note that `pQuantity` and `pPrice` are allocated but never freed.

---

Exam can be simplified, for instance :

```
ITEM *Exam(const char *pInput)
{
    ITEM *pItem = (ITEM *)malloc(sizeof(ITEM));
    const char *p;

    p = strchr(pInput, ',');
    pItem->pName = strndup(pInput, p - pInput);
    p += 1;

    pItem->Quantity = atoi(p);
    p = strchr(p, ',') + 1;

    pItem->Price = atoi(p);
    pItem->Total = pItem->Price * pItem->Quantity;

    return pItem;
}
```

Note that the input string is not modified (I moved it `const`) and there is no dynamic allocation except for the result and the name

---

if you do not have *strndup* :

```
char * strndup(const char * s, int n)
{
    char * r = (char *) malloc(n + 1);

    memcpy(r, s, n);
    r[n] = 0;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and knowledge sir!

Comment: @catify I added _strndup_ if you don't have it on visual-studio, and I added a missing _const_ in the declaration of _p_